# Generic declaration for Java Stream::*Match operations

Tags: java, generics, java-8, functional-interface

I would like to create a generic `test()` function to demonstrate the `Stream` operations `allMatch`, `anyMatch`, and `noneMatch`. It might look something like this (which doesn't compile):

```
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.function.*;

public class Tester {
    void test(Function<Predicate<Integer>, Boolean> matcher, int val) {
        System.out.println(
            Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5).matcher(n -> n < val));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test(Stream::allMatch, 10);
        test(Stream::allMatch, 4);
        test(Stream::anyMatch, 2);
        test(Stream::anyMatch, 0);
        test(Stream::noneMatch, 0);
        test(Stream::noneMatch, 5);
    }
}
```

(I think) my challenge is in defining `matcher` which probably needs to be a generic rather than the way I do it here. I'm also not sure if it's possible to make the calls I show here in `main()`.

I'm not even sure this can be done, so I'd appreciate any insights.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just write `System.out.println(list.stream().allMatch(predicate(10))` and do it straightforwardly rather than trying to wrap this up in a super-general way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works:

```
static void test(
      BiPredicate<Stream<Integer>, Predicate<Integer>> bipredicate, int val) {
    System.out.println(bipredicate.test(
         IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 5).boxed(), n -> n < val));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    test(Stream::allMatch, 10);
    test(Stream::allMatch, 4);
    test(Stream::anyMatch, 2);
    test(Stream::anyMatch, 0);
    test(Stream::noneMatch, 0);
    test(Stream::noneMatch, 5);
}
```

...but if the point is to *demonstrate* what these things do, you'd probably be better off writing the more straightforward

```
System.out.println(IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 5).allMatch(n -> n < 10));
```

..etcetera, which is a lot easier to read.

Comment: Hmm. Might there be a way to package the `BiPredicate<Stream<Integer>, Predicate<Integer>>` as another, simpler-looking type, so it doesn't look so intimidating right there? I note that `interface Matcher extends BiPredicate<Stream<Integer>, Predicate<Integer>> {}` works -- that seems to make it simple enough. Thanks!

Comment: @user1677663 Yes, you can define `interface Matcher extends BiPredicate<Stream<Integer>, Predicate<Integer>> {}` and replace the first parameter with `Matcher matcher`.